# ANGULAR E ASP.NET juntos no front-end

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, front-end

Estou com uma duvida, é possivel usar asp.net e angular no front end ?? tipo uma pagina é em asp.net e chama outra que é em angular ??

Pois estou trabalhando num projeto atualmemte onde o mesmo é em MVC Web e meu chefe pediu para eu fazer uma tela de cadastro em angular so para testar mas ele que que apareça dentro de uma pagina em View.html

Comment: Sim, é possivel, tanto que no Visual Studio é possivel criar projeto aspnet em Angular ou React se quiser. Agora... como vai ser feito é outro ponto que você terá q estudar, procure na net. Provavelmente essa sua pergunta irá ser fechada por algum adm.

Comment: então, ate o momento nao achei nada parecido na intenet, por isso vim aqui.